# How to configure NAT for SIP calls. No media transfer on pjsua SIP call to device through ssh port forwarding

Tags: ssh, sip, nat, pjsip, pjsua2

I have a machine `A` in a private network from which I would like to make a VOIP call over SIP using `pjsua` to a device `B` on a public IP address. Because of the firewall on the network, I need to use a "jump box" to route all the data through because I cannot access the IP address of `B` from machine `A`. I can see the public internet from the jump box and I can connect between `A` and the jump box via `ssh`. Thus, I can make target device `B` visible from `A` by forwarding its IP and ports to `localhost` ports on `A` over `ssh`.

Using such a setup to forward port 5060 for device `B`, from the jump box to the `localhost:5060` on machine `A`, I can open `pjsua` on `A` and make the call to `B`. I can see that the SIP transaction is successful and I get a `200 OK` message from the device `B`.

However, even if I also forward ports from 4000-4050 for RTP transport in the same manner, I cannot send media files to the device `B` for audio playback. I have confirmed that this is possible from another machine which is not behind a firewall the way `A` is, so I know that device `B` can receive files sent over `pjsua`.

I believe what is happening is that the SIP messages received from device `B` contain the IP address of `B`, along with the RTP port to send the media files to. So, rather than sending them to say `localhost:4000` which is forwarded to the right IP address, `pjsua` attempts to send to the IP address of `B` directly, which will be blocked by the firewall. (I'm not sure how to confirm this suspicion.) I believe I need to configure some kind of NAT on `A` or for `pjsua` specifically. However, I'm relatively inexperienced in SIP/pjsip, or in network configuration like this. I've tried using an `iptables` command such as the following:

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p all -d [IP_ADDR_B] -j DNAT --to-destination 127 .0.0.1`

but to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction to make this call work?

Comment: Check SDP of both sides during negotiation. IPs and ports in SDP will tell you everything you need. To read SDP set log level at least to 4, then look after INVITE headers, and after SIP 200 OK headers. If you don't understand SDP protocol, paste it here and I will try help you to walkthrough this.

Comment: Yes, I can see on the SDP payload -- line c=IN IP4 ... -- in the message coming back from my device (the 200 OK message) that the IP address is the router public IP. I need my machine A to send the audio to localhost to get through the ssh tunnel though. Should I expect the SDP from the device B to contain localhost or 127.0.0.1 as the IP? How would it know that it's "IP" should be localhost as viewed from machine A? This is where I don't understand how the NAT should work. Do I need a STUN server?